# Using SELECT COUNT(*) with NOCOUNT ON

Tags: sql-server

In MSSQL stored procedures, when writing an aggregated query such as "SELECT COUNT(*) ...." are the results adversely affected by the NOCOUNT ON setting? Or, will it just not show "1 rows"?

Comment: It won't show "X rows updated".
`select count(*)`  is counting rows of data.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You could test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SET NOCOUNT ON; only avoid to list a message that displays in the message tab (in SSMS). Is recommended (as best practices) that an application in production uses the SET NOCOUNT ON cause this is only used for debug environments.

The SELECT COUNT(*) doesn't have anything related to SET NOCOUNT, it only shows the "(1 row affected)" by the SELECT COUNT(*)